# Directly add to array in defaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, defaults

Is it okay to call this?

```
[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"searchEnginesOrder"] addObject:@"eBay"];
```

I have a `UITableView` whose cells I want to load directly from the defaults, and I also want to modify those defaults. I'm wondering if the above line actually has any effect (when I `NSLog` the default's array `searchEngineOrder` it's null, I'm wondering if it's because the above code isn't actually adding to the defaults.

Comment: Nope. Any object you get back from defaults is immutable. What you can do is get a mutable copy, append and save again.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, that line of code would crash. User defaults returns immutable objects so calling `addObject:` will throw an exception.

You also shouldn't rely on changes made to returned objects being backed into the data store - this isn't user defaults specific, it goes for any API which doesn't document it as supported.

You should be separating your logic between your working data and your stored data with defined modifications and save points. Ensure that you mutable copy the data you extract from user defaults. You should also use `registerDefaults:` to setup initial values so you don't need to check for existence.

Comment: It doesn't crash the program, but as far as I can see doesn't have any effect. Also, is it ok to do something like the following: 'dict = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey@"searchEnginesOrder"] mutableCopy]'? Thanks so far.

Comment: Not crashing probably means that you never set a value into defaults. Yes, you can mutable copy like that.

Comment: It's not crashing because in Objective C you can send any messages to nil, they just do nothing and return 0 (nil, NULL). As you haven't stored any object for @"searchEnginesOrder" key, your code is essentially  `[nil addObject:@"eBay"]`.

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults returns immutable objects. You have to create mutable copies in order to edit the values.

```
NSMutableDictionary *subSettings;

subSettings = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                objectForKey:YOUR_SUBMAP_KEY] mutableCopy];
[subSettings setObject:YOUR_NEW_VALUE forKey:YOUR_VALUE_KEY];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
  setObject:subSettings forKey:YOUR_SUBMAP_KEY];

[subSettings release];
```